# Access and modify user input bar in iMessage

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

Can I access and modify the text users can normaly enter to chat from an iMessage extension (how)?

Comment: This is not currently possible in iMessage extensions for privacy reasons.

Comment: Can you submit this as an answer? So I can close this.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible in iMessage extensions for privacy reasons.

More information can be found in the iMessage extension documentation on Apple's website.